# Difference between doctor-bag (Mastermind) and first-aid-kit (Fugative)?

Tags: payday-2

What is the difference between the two? (I just noticed the new class and recent changes yesterday and haven't had the time to play much)

I'm guessing it has something to do with potency and resetting your 'downs', is this an accurate guess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doctor Bags reset how many times you went down and bring you to full health. First Aid Kits give back small amounts of health but will not reset the number of times you went down (3 times).

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum:

- Bring Doctor Bags if you know you're going to have to camp at a certain objective for a while.  For example, Day 2 on Hoxton Breakout.  Since you will need to anticipate your allies going down, having a Doctor Bag will help prevent them from being taken into custody too many times
- Bring First Aid Kits if you know you'll be mobile.  Such as on Hoxton Breakout Day 1, since you'll be moving all the time to objectives, you don't have to "leave" a medic bag behind since the first aid kits are one-time use and can be put pretty much anywhere.

Comment: You could bring a doctor bag on Hoxton Breakout Day 1, and put it on the back of the truck instead of on the ground. Placing it down during the parking garage hacking would also be a good use of it.

Comment: You also get a LOT more first aid kits with the right choices in the Fugitive tree.  This works well in conjunction with the Muscle perk deck.